# Expanding Rows for Unique Checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, unique, rows

I was just recently given a project for my job to write a script that compares two mysql databases and print out information into an html table.  Currently, I am trying to insert a checkbox by each individual's name and when selected, rows pertaining to that individual will expand underneath the person's name.  I am combining javascript into my script to do this, although I really have no experience is it.  The problem I am having is that when any checkbox is selected, all the rows for each individual is expanding instead of the rows pertaining only to the one individual selected.

Here is my code so far:

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect ($server = "harris.lib.fit.edu", $username = "", $password =     "") or die(mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db ("library-test") or die(mysql_error());

$ids = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ifc_studylog`") or die(mysql_error()); //not single quotes (tilda apostrophy)

    $x=0;
    $n=0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $ids ))
    {           
        $tracksid1[$x] = $row['fitID'];
        $checkin[$x] = $row['checkin'];
        $checkout[$x] = $row['checkout'];

        $n++;
        $x++;
    }

$names = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ifc_users`") or die(mysql_error()); //not single quotes (tilda apostrophy)

    $x=0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $names ))
    {           
        $tracksnamefirst[$x] = $row['firstName'];
        $tracksnamesecond[$x] = $row['lastname'];
        $tracksid2[$x] = $row['fitID'];
        $tracksuser[$x] = $row['tracks'];

        $x++;           
    }           
$x=0;   

foreach($tracksid2 as $comparename)
{   
    $chk = strval($x);

?>
```

JS Code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.varx').click(function() {
        $('.text').toggle(this.checked);
    });
});​
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php       
    echo '<td><input id = "<?=$chk?>" type="checkbox" class="varx" /></td>';
    echo '<td align="center">'.$comparename.'</td>';
    echo'<td align="center">'.$tracksnamefirst[$x].'</td>';
    echo'<td align="center">'.$tracksnamesecond[$x].'</td>';        

    $z=0;

    foreach($tracksid1 as $compareid)
    {
        $HH=0;
        $MM =0;
        $SS =0;

        if($compareid == $comparename)// && $tracks==$tracksuser[$x])
        {

            $SS = sprintf("%02s",(($checkout[$z]-$checkin[$z])%60));
            $MM = sprintf("%02s",(($checkout[$z]-$checkin[$z])/60 %60));
            $HH = sprintf("%02s",(($checkout[$z]-$checkin[$z])/3600 %24));

             //  echo'<td align="center">'.$HH.':'.$MM.':'.$SS.'</td>';

                    echo '</tr>';

             echo '<tr>';
               echo "<td id='txt' class='text' align='center' colspan='2' style='display:none'></td>";
               echo "<td id='txt' class='text' align='center' style='display:none'>".$checkin[$z]."</td>";

               echo  '</tr>';

        }
        echo '<tr>';
        $z++;
        echo  '</tr>';
    }       
$x++;
}           
}   
?>
```

Any help is appreciated and apologies if I am too vague on the subject. The username and password have been left out for security reasons.